# Qt app fails to start in Release mode when launched from QtCreator ( Qt5widgets.dll error #c0000005 )

Tags: qt, dll, widget, qt5, release

I've developed a small Qt application with Qt Creator 4.0.3, based on Qt 5.7.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit). It has some GUI features, 2 UI forms, and does perform a few calculations. I work on Windows 7 SP1 (64 bits).

Anyway, it works fine in Debug mode (compiling and executing from Qt Creator). Compiling in Release mode is ok as well, but when I launch it in Release mode, the app crashes right from the start and I get the following error message:

> Nom d’événement de problème: APPCRASH
>   Nom du module par défaut: **Qt5Widgets.dll**
>   Code de l’exception: **c0000005**
>   Décalage de l’exception: 00000000000443f6
>   Version du système: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
>   Identificateur de paramètres régionaux: 1036
>   Information supplémentaire n° 1: 8ea0
>   Information supplémentaire n° 2: 8ea0c4174e0822e8b28dbc57f24bae2b
>   Information supplémentaire n° 3: 3b5a
>   Information supplémentaire n° 4: 3b5acddea433ec4f225b96ef9c334a03

I really can't guess how the problem could be solved and it prevents me from jumping to the next step in the deployment process (by the way, I get the same error when trying to execute the app directly when double-clicking it, even after using windeployqt and adding the required DLLs...).

Here's my .pro file:

```
QT += xml widgets network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += printsupport

HEADERS += \
    fenprincipale.h \
    quandldatadomdoc.h \
    historique.h \
    portfoliohistorique.h \
    portfolio.h \
    security.h \
    portfoliomodel.h \
    portfolioitem.h \
    portfoliodelegate.h \
    historicmanager.h \
    dialogvarhisto.h \
    qcustomplot.h \
    fengraphvar.h

SOURCES += \
    fenprincipale.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    quandldatadomdoc.cpp \
    historique.cpp \
    portfoliohistorique.cpp \
    portfolio.cpp \
    security.cpp \
    portfoliomodel.cpp \
    portfolioitem.cpp \
    portfoliodelegate.cpp \
    historicmanager.cpp \
    dialogvarhisto.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp \
    fengraphvar.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    resourcesro.qrc

FORMS += \
    dialogvarhisto.ui \
    fengraphvar.ui
```

EDIT :

Looking at JIT Visual Studio debugger windows , I get the following outputs :

Callstack :

```
Qt5Widgets.dll!00000000506843f6()   Unknown
    RiskOffice.exe!000000013f9f3c60()   Unknown
    RiskOffice.exe!000000013f9f16d1()   Unknown
    RiskOffice.exe!000000013f9f7795()   Unknown
    RiskOffice.exe!000000013fa34465()   Unknown
    RiskOffice.exe!000000013fa33dfd()   Unknown
    [External Code] 

--------------------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------

'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Widgets.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Gui.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Core.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mpr.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Xml.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Network.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winnsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvinitx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\bearer\qgenericbearer.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\bearer\qnativewifibearer.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wlanapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wlanutil.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qdds.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Svg.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'RiskOffice.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013_64\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x1edc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000506843F6 (Qt5Widgets.dll) in RiskOffice.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

...which say basically that some modules ( including Qt5Widgets.dll ) were "built without symbols" but I dont know how to interpret this...

Comment: When you're running Release build (but still under debugger) from within Qt Creator, do you get a callstack when it crashes?

Comment: A wild guess: an uninitialized variable. If you can't get anything sensible out of a debugger, you can always pin-point the problem by commenting out parts of your application until it doesn't crash anymore, and then restore piece-by-piece until you find out which exact part is the culprit.

Comment: Hi mike, jpnurmi, I've edited my question with some output of MSVC JIT debugger...Thx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had just forgotten to remove an uninitialized QAction object at the instantiation of my MainWindow. Adding it to the QMenuBar did not have the app crashed in debug mode but DID have it crashed in release mode ! Amazing !